# Python: Iterating through string with a for loop returns two lines when printing

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, iteration

I have written this little program to change camelCase function descriptions into snake_case descriptions.

```
def main():
    #Get input and pass it to function
    string = input("Camelcase: ")
    make_snake(string)

def make_snake(string):
    for char in string:
        if char.isupper():
            string = string.replace(char, "_"+ (char))
            string_new = string.lower()
            print(f"snake_case: {string_new}")

main()
```

It works fine with camelCase words with one capital letter like firstName, but when I run it with camelCases with two capital letters like "preferredFirstName" print returns two lines:

preferred_firstname
preferred_first_name

I want it to return only the second line.
Any idea why that is?
Thank you so much for your time!
Michael

Comment: Try decreasing the level of indentation of `print(f"...")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait till all letters have processed to print the converted string.

```
>>> def make_snake(string):
...     for char in string:
...         if char.isupper():
...             string = string.replace(char, "_"+ (char))
...     string_new = string.lower()
...     print("snake_case: "+string_new)
...
>>> make_snake('preferredFirstName')
snake_case: preferred_first_name
>>>
```

Comment: Oh, now I get it. It was the indentation. Wow, I would have never thought. thanks! That was really helpful! I very much appreciate it.